# Forcing a syncronous reactive extension call

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am working on some code which looks something like this:

```
public class ManagerViewModel : ManagerViewModelBase
{
  public ManagerViewModel(ISettingsProvider settingsProvider):
    base(settingsProvider.Settings)
}


public class ManagerViewModelBase
{
  private IEnumerable<string> _mySettings = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

  public ManagerViewModelBase(IEnumerable<string> settings)
  {
    _mySettings = settings;
  }
}
```

ISettingsProvider is provided via Unity and looks like:

```
public class SettingsProvider : ISettingsProvider 
{
  private readonly Service _service;
  IEnumerable<string> _settings = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

  public IEnumerable<string> Settings {get {return _settings}};

  public SettingsProvider (
    IService _service,
    ISettingsProvider settingsProvider)
  {
    _service = service;
    LoadSettings();
  }

  private void LoadSettings()
  {
    //_service just supplies the data              
    _service.GetSettings.Subscribe(LoadSettingsCompleted);
  }

  private void LoadSettingsCompleted(IEnumerable<string> settings)
  {
    _settings = settings;
  }
}
```

The issue is that when SettingsProvider is instantiated, it may take a little time to get the results from the service call and as a result, before the call is completed and _settings populated, the base(settingsProvider.Settings) call is made, basically passing on an empty enumerable.

Is there a way I can make the SettingsProvider.Settings property call wait until the data from the Service.GetSettings call is available, and timeout after a certain amount of time?  I guess I am looking for the simplest way to block on that property call.

Thanks.

Comment: How are we meant to help when you haven't given us the definition for the key bit of code? `_service.GetSettings`? The definition for `IService` would be an awesome addition to your question.

Comment: Having said that this code looks very synchronous. What advantage do you see by adding in asynchronous reactive framework calls?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this as well: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/ and if the asynchroncity is important, why not consider exposing the it directly on the interface itself as a `Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetSettings` or similar - if you are only returning the settings once. Incidentally, I've exposed settings directly as observables in the past in order to pick up changes to them immediately in an application with good success.

Comment: @JamesWorld I would love to read about how you have exposed application settings as observables in the past.

Answer (score 0):

None of this is very *reactive* but you could block using the `Observable.FirstAsync()` and `Observable.Wait()` extension methods. So your `LoadSettings()` method could look something like:

```
private void LoadSettings()
{
    _settings = _service.GetSettings
                        .Timeout(_expireTime, Observable.Return(Enumerable.Empty<string>()))
                        .FirstAsync()
                        .Wait();
    _service.GetSettings.Subscribe(LoadSettingsCompleted);
}
```

Comment: @Gluck your edit prevents the subscription to the IObservable returned from `_service.GetSettings`. Without this the `_settings` field will never be updated with new settings.

Comment: right, I didn't expect the settings observable was running updates and thought it provided a value then completed, but after reading the author question again, that fact no longer seem clear

Comment: @Gluck OK I've rolled back. I 100% agree with your answer: "I realized your question is how to wait/block, but I must tell you that you probably shouldn't."

Answer (score 0):

I realized your question is how to wait/block, but I must tell you that you probably shouldn't. Likely your ViewModel is getting created in the UI thread, and blocking is the last thing you want in there.

If your ViewModel relies on something asynchronous, then its creation is asynchronous, and you should hide that with the wait.
Async in constructor can't be used, but alternatively you can make your VM constructor private, and expose an async static factory method instead, something like:

```
private ManagerViewModel(IEnumerable<string> settings) : base(settings) {}

public async Task<ManagerViewModel> CreateAsync(ISettingsProvider settingsProvider) {
    var settings = await settingsProvider.GetSettingsAsync();
    return new ManagerViewModel(settings);
}

// ....

public async Task<IEnumerable<Settings>> GetSettingsAsync() {
    return await _service.GetSettings().Timeout(...).FirstAsync();
}
```

Expose async all the way and never block would be my recommandation.